# Error building Windows Phone project with build configuration ARM

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

The project can be compiled and deployed to the **Emulator and Device**.
Everything works fine as long as the build configuration is set at **AnyCPU** or **x86**. 
And is set to **Debug**.

---

**But when build configuration is set to Release, project doesn't build.
If project is set to AnyCPU and ARM, the same problem exists.**

Error   1

```
Files has invalid value "<?xml version="1.0"?>". Illegal characters in path.
```

The error doesn't point to a file.

External Libraries referenced by in this project-

```
 - JeffWilcox.PhoneThemeManager
 - Buddy
 - AdDuplex
```

Comment: have you used sqlite on that?

Comment: how many projects are in solution?

Comment: No sir. I Didn't use SQLite. There is only one project in the solution.

Comment: The problem has been updated. Please check.

Comment: you can not build ARM to emulator as it is x86 system

Comment: I am trying to build Release for ARM to deploy on Device.
The Debug Build is running on Device already.

Comment: is it telling some metadata file missing?

Comment: It doesn't say anything. It doesn't link to a file. Strange Problem.

Comment: what error it displaying?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Phone 8 emulator can run only applications built as AnyCPU or x86, because it is actually running on your PC as on Hyper-V as a virtual machine.
On the other hand all Windows Phone 8 devices are ARM only, so to run your app on device, it needs to be AnyCPU or ARM.
I hope this clears some confusion in the deployment limitations.

Comment: Thank You, but that is not the problem. Can't compile under Release Mode. Project complies under Debug Mode only. Target platform set to AnyCPU.